# ShaderMask not applying to full child

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem with the ShaderMask flutter widget covering a full icon. I am trying to replicate the Instagram gradient using the following code:

```
class RadiantGradientMask extends StatelessWidget {
  RadiantGradientMask({required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => RadialGradient(
        center: Alignment(-0.9, 0.9),
        radius: 1,
        colors: [
          Color(0xFFFEDA77),
          Color(0xFFF58529),
          Color(0xFFDD2A7B),
          Color(0xFF8134AF),
          Color(0xFF515BD4)
        ],
        stops: [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0],
        tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
      ).createShader(Offset.zero & bounds.size),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}


IconButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      await launchURL(
          'https://www.instagram.com/');
    },
    icon: RadiantGradientMask(
      child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,
          color: Colors.white, size: 40),
)),
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L83Uo.jpg)

I have tried adjusting the radius and center(alignment) variables and am lost for why the gradiant suddenly cuts off. I had originally covered the entire icon when it was size: 30, but the client wants larger icons and thus my issue. Thank you for any help.

Edit: in the mean time I'm simply reverting back to icon size 30 where the gradient works as expected, however I'll leave this open because I am still confused as to why the size would matter. From my understanding the gradient should grab the size of the container its covering (icon in this case) and scale accordingly and even if the gradient with the defined stops doesn't encompass the full child it should mirror (based on my configuration). Why it suddenly cuts to white at the edge of the icon is still unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Where the problem comes from

The problem has to do with the `Icon` widget and the specific icon you are using. As explained [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52980), icons can overflow their container within the `Icon` widget. This has to do with the inner workings of this widget:

```
Widget iconWidget = RichText( 
   overflow: TextOverflow.visible, // Never clip. 
   ...
);
```

This seems to be an unsolved issue – again see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52980).

The `ShaderMask` now only masks the bounds of the `Icon` widget; however, these bounds are overflown.

### Workaround

A workaround for this issue is to wrap the `Icon` widget in a `Container` as follows:

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  width: iconSize,
  height: iconSize,
  child: Icon(
    iconData,
    size: iconSize * 0.9,
  ),
)
```

One has to play around with the factor `0.9` and the `alignment` property.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a better solution right now.